# How to return an immutable List in Dart?

Tags: dart

So in other languages there are `ArrayList` or `MutableList` which allows modifications (add, delete, remove) to list items. Now to avoid modification of these list, simply return the `MutableList` or `ArrayList` as a `List`.

I want to do the same thing in `Dart`. But in `Dart` returning a `List` still allows you to do `list.add`. How can this be done properly in Dart?

Comment: Try [List.unmodifiable](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.1/dart-core/List/List.unmodifiable.html)

Comment: Alternative, use the [UnmodifiableListView](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.1/dart-collection/UnmodifiableListView-class.html) from dart:collection which has it own type so you can indicate that the list are unmodifiable.

Comment: @julemand101 feels more like a work around than a solution :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no *type* for unmodifiable lists in Dart, just the `List` type.
Some `List` implementations accept calling `add`, others do not.

You can return an *actually* unmodifiable list, say created using `List.unmodifiable`, as a `List`. The user will get a run-time error if they try to call `add` on it.

Answer (score 25):

You may use [`Iterable<type>`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable-class.html). It is not a `List<type>`, it does not provide methods to modify, but it does to iterate. It also provides a `.toList()` method, if needed. Depending on your construction, it may be better to use `Iterable` instead of `List` to ensure consistency.

#### Almost good

```
final Iterable<int> foo = [1, 2, 3];
foo.add(4); // ERROR: The method 'add' isn't defined.

// WARNING: following code can be used to mutate the container.
(foo as List<int>).add(4);
print(foo); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Even though `foo` is instantiated as a mutable `List`, the interface only says it is an `Iterable`.

#### Good

Using [`List<E>.unmodifiable`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/List.unmodifiable.html) constructor:

```
final Iterable<int> foo = List.unmodifiable([1, 2, 3]);
foo.add(4); // ERROR: The method 'add' isn't defined.

(foo as List<int>).add(4); // Uncaught Error: Unsupported operation: add

// The following code may appear to be circumventing 
// the implemented restriction, but it is 
// OK because it does not mutate foo; rather, 
// foo.toList() returns a separate instance.
foo.toList().add(4);
print(foo); // [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 16):

*As Irn said, there is no type for immutable lists in Dart, but this supplemental answer shows examples of creating immutable lists. You can't add, remove, or modify the list elements.*

## Compile time constant list variables

Use the `const` keyword to create the list.

```dart
const myList = [1, 2, 3];
```

*Note*: Adding the optional `const` keyword before the list literal is redundant when the variable is already `const`.

```dart
const myList = const [1, 2, 3];
```

## Compile time constant list values

If the variable can't be a `const`, you can still make the value be `const`.

```dart
final myList = const [1, 2, 3];
```

## Runtime constant list

If you don't know what the list elements are until runtime, then you can use the `List.unmodifiable()` constructor to create an immutable list.

```dart
final myList = List.unmodifiable([someElement, anotherElement]);
```

Answer (score 6):

To prevent modifications on your list, just use a [`UnmodifiableListView`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-collection/UnmodifiableListView-class.html) from the built-in [**dart:collection**](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-collection/dart-collection-library.html) library:

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

List<int> protectedNumbersUntil4() {
  return UnmodifiableListView([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);
}

final numbers = protectedNumbersUntil4();
numbers.add(5); // throws
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `IList` an immutable list from `package:darts/dartz.dart` the next best solution would be to use `KtList` (which is an immutable Kotlin collection), both are immutable and will serve as immutable lists, however, I prefer `KtList` as it is much easier to use.

Also, check out this medium post on immutability *( https://medium.com/dartlang/an-intro-to-immutability-with-dart-d4de871865c7 )*

And this one on ktlist *https://medium.com/flutter-community/kt-dart-better-collections-for-your-flutter-business-logic-41886ab7883*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `BuiltList` in `built_collection`